# how to use substring in an update statement in ms sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring

I have tow tables each table has date column I want to update the date of the 1st table to be the date in the 2nd table with out changing the time only the yyyy-mm-dd

```
select substring(CONVERT(varchar(25), r1.date1, 121),1,10),
       substring(CONVERT(varchar(25), r2.date2, 121),1,10)
from table1 r1 join
     table2 r2
     on r1.Number = r2.Number

update r1
    set r1.date1=substring(CONVERT(varchar(25), r1.[Time], 121),1,10) = substring(CONVERT(varchar(25), r2.date2, 121),1,10)
    from table1 r1 join
         table2 r2 
         on r1.Number = r2.Number
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Also, why don't your queries work?

Comment: I suggest you use datediff and dateadd to adjust the desired value by adding/subtracting the appropriate number of days - which will leave the time portion unaffected. An example of your goal would help others understand your issue more completely.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right then you need to update r1.date1 with the date part of r2.date2 and time part of r1.date1. You can do it with below query:

```
update r1
    set r1.date1=cast(concat(cast( r2.date2 as date),' ',convert(varchar, r1.date1, 114)) as datetime)
    from table1 r1 join
         table2 r2 
         on r1.Number = r2.Number
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `convert` for this. Use `dateadd` and `datediff` instead for simple arithmetic.

```sql
update r1
    set r1.date1 =
      dateadd(day,
        datediff(cast(r1.date1 as date), cast(r2.date2 as date)),
        r1.date1)
from table1 r1
join table2 r2 
    on r1.Number = r2.Number
```